# Apply new Windows shell context menu item to encrypted files

Tags: windows, shell, context-menu

I am trying to add a context menu item which will only appear if a file is marked as being encrypted.

With an `AppliesTo` entry, I can successfully apply the menu item to only text files with `System.FileExtension:=".txt"`, however if I try to use the [System.IsEncrypted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc184966(v=vs.85).aspx) property: `System.IsEncrypted:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True`, the item will not display.

I have tried using different values after the `System.IsEncrypted` condition and testing with both encrypted and unencrypted files to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `AttributeMask` and `AttributeValue` settings to achieve the same purpose.

An `AttributeMask` and `AttributeValue` of 0x2000 (8192) will test whether the file is encrypted.